# Why does chmod have two different meanings for 5?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I think I have a pretty solid understanding of file permissions, but there's one specific set of permissions that has an element I don't understand.

The permission set 0755 should show as `rwx-rx-rx`

But in my terminal 0755 shows as `rwx-rx-x`

Why is the 5 in the "Other/World" position only showing as execute while the "Group" permission is 5, but shows as read/execute?

I've Googled for the answer, but every similar question I found was answered with an explanation of the permission table, but never addressed the two different values of 5.

Comment: Your permission expressions are wrong..check again..

Comment: That seems kind of hard to believe. Could you please [edit] your question to include the verbatim output of `stat -c '%A %a  %n' FILE` (where `FILE` is a file with the appropriate permission mask, e. g. `/`)?

Answer (score 1):

Permission values are octal, and represent 3 3-bit fields. `5` has only one value `0b101`. The permissions you are trying to set are masked with your `umask` value, which, I surmise is `026` That is:

```
Value you're trying to set: 755 or 0b111101101
Umask                       026 or 0b000010110
-----------------------------------------------
Actual bits used by `chmod` 751 or 0b111101001
Going back to rwx, the bits are      rwxrwxrwx
And the actual permissions set are   rwxr-x--x
```

See `man umask`.

The three digits in the permission (there are a few more but that's the advanced course) specify file access permissions for the file's Owner (first octal digit), users with the same GID as the file (second octal digit), and Everybody else (not owner, not same group ID) (third octal digit).